# app-all.js not working with ext.js

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using sencha sdk tool 2 to build my extjs 4 application. Build is working fine and it generated two files -

1. app-all.js - minified
2. all-classes.js - non-minified

But when I am using minified app-all.js with ext.js in my index-mini.html page it is not working and giving me the error "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" at Ext.util.Cookies.get()

My application is working fine when I am using ext-all.js instead of ext.js.

I saw that my application is using some util classes(like - Ext.util.Cookies) that are not present in ext.js. Also for development we are using ext-all.js in our index.html but for deployment we want to use ext.js.

Questions - 
How can I run my application using ext.js & app-all.js?

-
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **ext-all.js** (and the un-minified **ext-debug.js**) only provide the minimum number of core ExtJS classes needed to get up and running. Any additional classes should be dynamically loaded as separate files

Section 2.2 of [Getting Started](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#%21/guide/getting_started-section-2) describes this, and also explains that you should dynamically load any additional classes.

Basically, you need to include a requires statement in your application as shown below.

```
requires:[
    'Ext.util.Cookies'
],
```